# Python decorator eats function results

Tags: python, function, python-decorators

Running python 3.9 on MacOS 13.4.1 on 2020 iMac 27".
While trying to use a decorator to time the execution time of a function, I have found that the value returned by the function being timed is reduced to 'None'. The timing_decorator is copied from a forgotten source. It works fine with functions that return no value.

```
import time

def timing_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.time()
        print(f"Function {func.__name__} took {end_time - start_time:7.3f} seconds to run.")        
        return
    return wrapper

@timing_decorator   
def funky(p1,p2):
    return p1 * p2

print(funky(6,7))
```

Running this code as is prints 'None'.
Commenting out the line '@timing_decorator' prints the expected result '42'
I have found quite a few references for passing parameters **to** the decorated function but nothing about the return values.

Comment: Note how you don't do anything with `result`. That's the return value.

Comment: Thank you @Carcigenicate for taking the time to state the obvious!!

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is simply return 'result' inside of function 'wrapper'.
Like this:

```
import time

def timing_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.time()
        print(f"Function {func.__name__} took {end_time - start_time:7.3f} seconds to run.")        
        return result # Return the actual result of the normal function instead of nothing
    return wrapper

@timing_decorator   
def funky(p1,p2):
    return p1 * p2

print(funky(6,7))
```

This returns what your decorator is expected to do, and 42, the result of your function 'funky'

Answer (score 0):

Your `wrapper` function in the `timing_decorator` is returning `None` implicitly by not returning anything after computing and printing the function's runtime, and I think it's the problem.

In order to fix this problem, you can return the `result` after computing the elapsed time.

I revised your code and it's here:

```py
import time

def timing_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.time()
        print(f"Function {func.__name__} took {end_time - start_time:7.3f} seconds to run.")        
        return result  # return the result from the wrapped function
    return wrapper

@timing_decorator   
def funky(p1,p2):
    return p1 * p2

print(funky(6,7))
```

By making this change, the `funky` function's return value (in this case, `42`) will be returned and printed as expected.